# How to read large files from HTTP response in Apache Beam?

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Apache Beam's TextIO can be used to read JSON files in some filesystems, but how can I create a PCollection out of a large JSON (InputStream) resulted from a HTTP response in Java SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a generic built-in solution in Beam to do this at the moment, [see the list of supported IOs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/).

I can think of multiple approaches to this, whichever works for you may depend on your requirements:

- I would probably first try to build another layer (probably not in Beam) that saves the HTTP output into a GCS bucket (maybe splitting it into multiple files in the process) and then use Beam's TextIO to read from the GCS bucket;
- depending on the properties of the HTTP source you can consider:

  - writing your own [`ParDo`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) that reads the whole response in a single step, splits it and outputs the split elements separately. Then further transforms would parse the JSON or do other stuff;
  - implementing [you own source](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/authoring-overview/), that will be more complicated but probably work better for very large (unbounded) responses;

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely take a look at these options