# Dataflow - Apache beam - Reading CSV (from external source : internet)

Tags: python-3.x, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Morning, I came across with a project that I need to create a pipeline that reads a csv file in the internet. I wonder if Apache beam has a method to do that ? Something like this :

```
beam.io.ReadFromText("https://www.samples.com/file.csv")
```

My current pipeline is :

```
    data =DownloadFileCSV()    #LOAD FILE INTO MEMORY
    fileCSV = data 

    #CRIA O PIPELINE
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        
        #CARREGA O ARQUIVO CSV DO SITE
        elements = p | 'Load File CSV' >> beam.Create(fileCSV) 

        #SALVA O ARQUIVO NO BUCKET DO GCP
        elements | 'Save new file to GCS' >>  beam.ParDo(WriteBatchesToGCS(nmBucket))
```

I would like to replace the line :

```
elements = p | 'Load File CSV' >> beam.Create(fileCSV)
```

I don't want to keep a part of the process out of the pipeline. So, Can Apache beam do it ?

Thank you,
Juliano

Comment: This could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53137454/how-to-read-large-files-from-http-response-in-apache-beam

Comment: thank you @pradeep